# How do you filter out the tags?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = "https://www.google.com/";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a");

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

---

My question is, the result comes out with bunch of extra tags, such as:

> - a: <>  (Reinstall to stay secure)
> - a: https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/?fg=1&utm_source=google-US&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-header  (About)
> - a: https://store.google.com/utm_source=hp_header&utm_medium=google_oo&utm_campaign=GS100042  (Store)
> - a: <>  (Reinstall to stay secure)

Can anyone show me how to remove things such as "*", "a", "<>" and it just displays the links only?

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the format string, for `String.format()`. In your case the `msg` value:

```
print("%s", link.attr("abs:href"));
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.